# Getting error connecting for the first time to HBase using Phoenix driver

Tags: java, hbase, mybatis, apache-phoenix

Using Phoenix driver I am connecting to HBase. Everything works, but there is an error stacktrace in the log while getting a connection. Again, it works fine, functionally no issues.

```
DataSource dataSource = getDataSource();
    TransactionFactory transactionFactory = new JdbcTransactionFactory(); 
    Environment environment = new Environment("test", transactionFactory, dataSource);
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration(environment);
    configuration.addMappers("co.mybatis.mapper");
    return new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(configuration);
public static DataSource getDataSource() {
return new UnpooledDataSource("org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver", CDH_UAT, "", "") {

        @Override
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
            Connection connection = super.getConnection();// i see error stacktrace here
            connection.setSchema("xxx");

            return connection;

        }
}}
```

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.AccessDeniedException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.AccessDeniedException: Insufficient permissions (user=userid@mydomain.COM, scope=SYSTEM, params=[namespace=SYSTEM,table=SYSTEM:CATALOG],action=CREATE)

For the first time, it prints error stacktrace, but afterwards all looks good. It seems for the first time while getting the connection it tries to **upsert into system catalog table**, not sure why.

How do I get rid of this error?